# Are Firebase dynamic links short url info exposable?

Tags: firebase-security, firebase-dynamic-links

Can an attacker view the query parameters of a shortened firebase dynamic link?

If yes, is it secure enough to use let’s say invite links that contain a group ID to access that certain group.

In that case wouldn’t there technically be the security issue of someone having a program attempt all ids till they get a correct ID?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, the url parameters **are indeed exposed and viewable**.

Secondly, firebase document ID's consist of 20 characters, each character could be 26 * 2 (Alphabet Capital and small) + 10 number possibilities. Meaning that an ID has **62^20 combinations**, Good luck to anyone trying that amount out.

Thirdly, i believe App attest would block a user if he's abusing resources.